# Local spark submit does not return any results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am trying to the below script locally using spark submit it does not return. The same code works in spark shell. Not sure what am I missing?

Spark Submit

```
./bin/spark-submit \
 --master local\
 ~/Desktop/projects/S3_Snowflake_Prototype/main.py
```

Code: main.py

```
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("PythonPi")\
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .load("~/Desktop/projects/S3_Snowflake_Prototype/csv/source.csv")

df.count()
```

Current Output

```
21/08/03 08:36:48 WARN Utils: Your hostname, vinays-MacBook-Pro.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.0.3 instead (on interface en0)
21/08/03 08:36:48 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
21/08/03 08:36:48 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/08/03 08:36:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/08/03 08:36:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/_l/r0yqws8j5hl5bsc5rvzjkm5c0000gn/T/spark-a3ea7970-7ef7-4edd-a539-f5c1f264b59d
```

Comment: try: `print(df.count())`

Comment: I am able to run the scripts in the example folder (like pi.py) and get results using spark submit. But If I use a script from a different location outside of the spark folder it does not seem to return any results.

Comment: @Steven I think the issue was I had two folders with same name one with underscores and one w/o. I think that was causing spark to confuse. Once I removed the folder w/o underscores it seems to work fine.